# gcloud logging read not returning anything, no errors either

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm trying to retreive all the logs within a specific time, here is my command:

```
gcloud logging read 'timestamp<="2022-08-15T12:50:00Z" AND timestamp>="2022-08-15T13:20:00Z"' --bucket=pre-prod --project=non-prod --location=global --view=_AllLogs --freshness=3d
```

I've specified the freshness, but it just returns nothing, no errors either.

Anyone know why this is not working? I can see the logs on the GCP console for the above dates, but logging read just not working.

Comment: Your timestamps conflict.... Before 12:50 and after 13:20 is false for everything

Comment: Also -- although I think there's possibly no consequence -- you can't use `--freshness` with a filter that includes timestamps. From the docs "Return entries that are not older than this value. Works only with DESC ordering and filters without a timestamp"

Comment: Oh my bad about the timestamps, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had wrong timestamps, needed to swap the greater than and lower than symbols.